# Will throwing an exception for bad pointer access ever be standard behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, standards

I did a quick search on Google and wasn't able to find anything relevant to this exact topic.

As C++ continues to move toward being a more modern language, including lambdas, range based for loops, etc, it seems like this question may eventually come up, if it hasn't already.

I don't see how this could be anything but a good thing, and provide the same benefits that have been proven useful in C++/CLI, C#, Java, etc. And if anyone didn't want this behavior, It could simply be made optional, and turned off with a compiler setting, the same way one would disable standard exceptions or RTTI.

Also, it has been suggested, but discouraged that one could create a signal handler for SIGSEGV and throw an exception from there, to simulate the suggested behavior. Now, although this is a bit of a hack, and not guaranteed to work on all platforms, how hard could it really be to implement null reference exceptions in C++ if the same basic behavior can be simulated(non-standardly) with around 10 lines of code?

So, is there any reason technical, or otherwise, that throwing an exception for bad pointer access couldn't eventually become part of the standard in the future?

Comment: wow, two downvotes, no comments...

Comment: Just to be clear, "null reference exception" != "exception for bad pointer access".  C++ has a lot of language rules for encouraging type safety, but falls far far short of guaranteeing it.  Which means you can have all sorts of invalid pointers and references that aren't NULL.

Comment: Define what a *bad pointer* is. If you say dereferencing a pointer to NULL, what about embedded systems where zero might be a perfectly valid memory address. And even discounting those edge cases, I'd say a far bigger problem is dereferencing a pointer filled with some random value. Can you think of a reliable way to detect that?

Comment: @Praetorian: "I'd say a far bigger problem is dereferencing a pointer filled with some random value" Interesting point, because it had not occurred to me that this case is not possible in C#/Java due to the lack of a delete operator.

Comment: in my original question, I was referring to accessing a null pointer, out of range pointer, or an already freed pointer.

Comment: How could you tell if a pointer was 'out of range'?  Range checking on array indexes is obviously possible, but I cannot see how any runtime pointer check could be implemented, (@Praetorian).  What would it check the pointer against?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: To properly answer this question, one needs to be able to see into the future with accuracy. That is pretty easy for short periods of time, but the longer, the less certain it gets. My reply here should be seen as an attempt do foresee into the near future. Whether this happens in 20-30 years, who can tell?

On the one hand, from a technical perspective:

The problem is that NULL references is just ONE possible scenario of bad pointer. If you stick some random garbage into a pointer variable, or access memory after free, or something else that causes a bad memory access will also cause SIGSEGV. That's the first problem.

The second problem is that not all hardware and/or software combinations allow detection of bad pointer access - or a way to continue AFTER a bad pointer access.

Simply adding `if (ptr != NULL) ...` before EVERY pointer dereference [where the compiler doesn't know for sure it is a valid pointer] would make C++ unbearably slow.

From a philosophical perspective, using RAII:
You shouldn't use "raw" pointers in your code, and `new` will cause `std::bad_alloc` exception if the system is out of memory. There is really no reason why a pointer should be invalid in RAII-style C++. If you are not using RAII, then you probably SHOULD be.

C++ was designed to be a language that is fast first, and sophisticated second.

Answer (score 0):

> Will throwing an exception for bad pointer access ever be standard
>   behavior in C++?

You can detect bad pointer accesses and the language allows you to throw exceptions accordingly.

As you say C++ includes lambdas, range based for loops, etc. It gives you rich possibilities but never gets in your way and force you to do something. So I don't think the standard will force such behavior and it should not.

Answer (score 0):

No, never. The fundamental rule of exceptions is that they are thrown **by a `throw` statement**. This makes it possible to encapsulate code that might throw exceptions within a `try` block. If pretty much any statement could throw an exception it would become **much** harder to reason about exception safety.

If your pointers are out of control, fix them.